# Create a vector in a matrix using data from a dataframe conditioned to variable values in the matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe

this is a bit hard to explain in writing, I'll do my best. (this is also my first post here). So,
I have dataframe "**x**" like this:

```
+---+----+----+-----+
|   | A  | B  | C   |
| 1 | 50 | 40 | 30  |
| 2 | 60 | 80 | 40  |
| 3 | 70 | 30 | 20  |
| 4 | 10 | 40 | 100 |
| 5 | 35 | 50 | 20  |
| 6 | 20 | 50 | 30  |
+---+----+----+-----+
```

And a matrix "**Y**" like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | C | C | B | A | A |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

(Assume the letters are numbers, I use letters just to explain more clearly). Now I want 'R' to create a new row in "**Y**" matrix extracting data from "**X**" dataframe depending on the values of the first and second row of the matrix. So, for example, for the third column in matrix "**Y**", the extracted value from the dataframe would be 20. Since on the first row the value is "C" and on the second row the value is "5" and in the dataframe the value where "C" and "5" intersect is 20. So, basically I need 'R' to use the data in the first and second row from the matrix and go to the dataframe and check with the first row and column for each value when both conditions are met and extract that value in the intersection, creating a third row in the matrix "**X**" containing the corresponding value for that column. Using the example tables, the third row should look like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | C  | C  | B  | A  | A  |
| 1  | 5  | 5  | 4  | 3  | 6  |
| 50 | 20 | 20 | 40 | 70 | 20 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I hope it was clear enough, I think the function to do this is "subset" but I dont really know how to get the desired result. Thanks for any help given.

EDIT: The following data is dataframe"**X**"

```
structure(list(X = structure(c(52L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 25L, 26L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L), .Label = c("0", "0.5", "1", "1.5", 
"10", "10.5", "11", "11.5", "12", "12.5", "13", "13.5", "14", 
"14.5", "15", "15.5", "16", "16.5", "17", "17.5", "18", "18.5", 
"19", "19.5", "2", "2.5", "20", "20.5", "21", "21.5", "22", "22.5", 
"23", "23.5", "24", "24.5", "25", "3", "3.5", "4", "4.5", "5", 
"5.5", "6", "6.5", "7", "7.5", "8", "8.5", "9", "9.5", "v"
), class = "factor"), AD = c(0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 15, 50, 94, 147, 209, 280, 361, 455, 564, 689, 830, 978, 1130, 
1281, 1431, 1579, 1728, 1872, 2011, 2144, 2263, 2353, 2418, 2462, 
2489, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500), X.1 = c(0.925, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 16, 52, 97, 151, 215, 288, 372, 469, 581, 
710, 854, 1006, 1161, 1315, 1467, 1619, 1770, 1915, 2055, 2189, 
2300, 2381, 2439, 2477, 2496, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500), X.2 = c(0.95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 17, 54, 100, 
156, 222, 297, 383, 483, 599, 731, 879, 1034, 1192, 1348, 1503, 
1657, 1810, 1956, 2096, 2230, 2331, 2405, 2455, 2488, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500), X.3 = c(0.975, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 18, 56, 104, 161, 228, 305, 394, 497, 616, 
752, 903, 1061, 1222, 1381, 1539, 1696, 1849, 1996, 2135, 2260, 
2354, 2421, 2465, 2491, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500), X.4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 19L, 58L, 
107L, 165L, 234L, 314L, 405L, 511L, 634L, 773L, 929L, 1097L, 
1274L, 1459L, 1649L, 1840L, 2030L, 2199L, 2327L, 2415L, 2470L, 
2495L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 
2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 
2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L, 2500L), X.5 = c(1.025, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 20, 60, 110, 170, 241, 322, 416, 525, 651, 795, 953, 
1125, 1307, 1497, 1692, 1889, 2084, 2245, 2362, 2440, 2485, 2499, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500
), X.6 = c(1.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 21, 62, 113, 175, 247, 
331, 427, 539, 668, 816, 978, 1154, 1340, 1535, 1735, 1937, 2132, 
2284, 2391, 2459, 2494, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500), X.7 = c(1.075, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 22, 64, 116, 179, 254, 339, 438, 553, 685, 836, 1002, 1182, 
1373, 1572, 1778, 1986, 2175, 2316, 2414, 2473, 2497, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500), 
    X.8 = c(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 24, 66, 120, 184, 260, 
    348, 449, 566, 702, 856, 1026, 1211, 1406, 1610, 1821, 2035, 
    2217, 2349, 2437, 2486, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500), X.9 = c(1.125, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 25, 68, 123, 189, 267, 356, 460, 580, 
    719, 877, 1051, 1239, 1439, 1648, 1864, 2080, 2254, 2377, 
    2455, 2495, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500), X.10 = c(1.15, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 26, 70, 126, 193, 273, 365, 471, 594, 736, 
    897, 1075, 1267, 1472, 1686, 1908, 2119, 2284, 2397, 2467, 
    2496, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500), X.11 = c(1.175, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 27, 72, 129, 198, 279, 373, 482, 608, 753, 917, 
    1099, 1295, 1505, 1724, 1952, 2158, 2313, 2418, 2478, 2498, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500), X.12 = c(1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 28, 74, 132, 203, 286, 382, 493, 622, 770, 937, 1123, 
    1324, 1537, 1761, 1995, 2197, 2343, 2439, 2489, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500), X.13 = c(1.225, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 29, 
    76, 136, 207, 292, 390, 504, 635, 787, 958, 1147, 1352, 1570, 
    1799, 2036, 2231, 2368, 2454, 2496, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500), X.14 = c(1.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 30, 78, 139, 212, 
    298, 399, 515, 649, 803, 978, 1171, 1380, 1603, 1838, 2071, 
    2257, 2386, 2464, 2497, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500), X.15 = c(1.275, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 31, 80, 142, 217, 305, 407, 525, 662, 
    820, 998, 1195, 1408, 1636, 1877, 2107, 2284, 2404, 2473, 
    2498, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500), X.16 = c(1.3, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 32, 82, 145, 221, 311, 415, 536, 676, 836, 
    1018, 1219, 1437, 1668, 1915, 2142, 2310, 2423, 2483, 2499, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
    2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500)), .Names = c("X", "AD", 
"X.1", "X.2", "X.3", "X.4", "X.5", "X.6", "X.7", "X.8", "X.9", 
"X.10", "X.11", "X.12", "X.13", "X.14", "X.15", "X.16"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-52L))
```

I cannot paste all data from matrix "**Y**" because its too big, its a 3x1644 matrix.
Here are the first few columns of the matrix "**Y**" though.

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("", "AD", "WS"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1.2", "3.5", "V1"
    ), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1.2", 
    "4", "V2"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("1.2", "3.5", "V3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "matrix", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Please note that the matrix turned into a dataframe when I extracted the first columns to post them here, but it still is a matrix in my data.

Comment: Can you replace your current presentations of data with the output of `dput(x)` and `dput(Y)`? It's a lot easier to give help if we can see the actual form of the data.

Comment: I am afraid I dont know how to change the presentation of the data, I dont know how to use dput()

Comment: If your object (matrix, dataframe, etc.) is called `x` and you type `dput(x)` into your R console. It will give you some output. If you copy and paste that output into your question, we will be able to see exactly what your data look like.

Comment: @RabidHealer, sorry, but your sample data doesn't even closely resemble what you originally asked. Can you please edit your question to include a minimal *working* example that demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
rbind(Y, sapply(seq_along(Y), 
                function(z) 
                  X[Y[1, z], names(Y)[z]]))
#    A  C  C  B  A  A
# 1  1  5  5  4  3  6
# 2 50 20 20 40 70 20
```

Here, I'm basically subsetting using `[` to match the values you're looking for.

---

For convenience of others, here's `X` and `Y`:

```
X <- structure(list(A = c(50, 60, 70, 10, 35, 20), 
                    B = c(40, 80, 30, 40, 50, 50), 
                    C = c(30, 40, 20, 100, 20, 30)), 
               .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), 
               row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
               class = "data.frame")
Y <- structure(list(A = 1, C = 5, C = 5, B = 4, A = 3, A = 6), 
               .Names = c("A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "A"), 
               row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: When I use your solution I get an error saying the subscript is out of bounds. Also I noticed the tables I posted are not showing as they should, the first rows of all 3 tables are shown as headers but they are not, they were meant to be shown with no headers. @Thomas I will try to do as you said to post the data, but I am afraid they are quite big

Comment: @RabidHealer, we don't need your exact data, just something similar that recreates the problem you are tying to solve.